# how to store and load files from runnable jar java

Tags: java, jar, path

I have this code:

```
public String chromePosition = "chromedriver.exe";
public String adBlock = "Adblock-Plus_v.crx";

public class MyCode{ //my code }
```

chromedriver.exe and the other file are stored inside my project's classpath. It works perfectly but when I export my project into a runnable jar file it cannot find my files. Why?
I've noticed that those files aren't inside the jar file so it cannot find them, how do I solve the problem?

Comment: If the files are stored within the Jar (embedded), then you'll need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to gain access to them at run time

Comment: Most IDEs have an option to export files other than those of the compiled .class files so you'd first have to make sure to do that. If your IDE doesn't have an option like that, you can just treat the jar file like a zip file and open it with 7zip and drag the needed files into the jar.
You will also have to use Class#getResource like the above comment says.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the jar and the other files inside the same folder.